# Redirect Rule in web.config not including folder path

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I'm working on a client application where they have a nested HTML-only app in a rooted subfolder of an otherwise ASP.NET application.

The domain name is changing for the HTML app only, and I need to be sure that the requests are routed to the new domain name.  So, using the `rewriteRules` sounds like a perfect tool for this, but I'm doing something wrong and need another set of eyes.

The original URL is something like this:

`https://example.com/folder1/folder2/app/index.html`

The new domain is on an entirely different server and I want all requests from the `app` folder to go to the new domain name.  Here is an example:

`https://newdomain.com/folder1/folder2/app/index.html`

Unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong that's probably obvious...  I keep getting this URL in the redirect.

`https://newdomain.com/index.html`

Here is the web.config showing what I tried.  It's in the `app` folder.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RedirectHtmlApp" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://newdomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`{R:0}` and `{R:1}` both return `index.html`.

Comment: I get the same output with `{R:0}` by the way.

Comment: Is URL Rewrite Module installed in the latter IIS instance?

Comment: You had me thinking for a minute.  There isn't a redirect there, though. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

What is passed to {R:0} is relative. So if your web.config is in /folder1/folder2/app/{here} then "folder1/folder2/app/" are not passed along. If your web.config rule is in the root of the site-app above /folder1, then I am wrong, but if I am right, then you just need to include the path to the root of the app at the destination also. Given what you have above,

```
<action type="Redirect"
 url="https://newdomain.com/folder1/folder2/app/{R:0}" 
 redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Comment: The web.config is not in the root of the site.  It's in the app folder.

Comment: Then it is relative. Read the last paragraph of this section of the docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#accessing-url-parts-from-a-rewrite-rule

Comment: I used the `{PATH_INFO}` parameter from the docs. This resolved the issue.

Comment: Yup, same-same. I recommend not using PATH_INFO though because there is no reason to believe the path on the old server could or should match the path on the new server. It will be better self-documenting if you hard code it in this case. IMHO